# Finding all elements in list view in appium

Tags: android, listview, selenium, mobile, appium

I have some 200 items in the List view. When I'm printing the size of the list view it prints only the visible items count(Eg. 10 items). It doesn't scroll and print all the items. How to take all the items in the list view.

Comment: where (and how) are you "printing" them?

Comment: List<WebElement> customer_name= ds.findElements(By.id(ivs.customer_list_name));<br/>

   
   for(int i=0;i<customer_name.size();i++)
   <br/>{<br/>

    <br/>System.out.println(customer_name.get(i).getText().toString());
   <br/>}

Comment: see `Adapter#getItem`

Comment: thanks man can you give the code for that.

Comment: i gave you code for that: use `getItem` method

Comment: @Pradap Pandian,
'found' not seems to be declared cuz it's not boolean variable he declared, above he use a var with name 'found_result', but below it's 'found' :D, in listview we've visible elements and invisible elements, driver.swipe() will find invisible elements, please debug will help you understand this problem!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//Try this below the code
String a = "Last element name"; /// last element in the list
Boolean found_result = false;

while (!found_result){

    List<WebElement> ele = driver.findElements(By.id("id of your element"));
    int size=0;
     size = size+ele.size();

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {

        String s = ele.get(i).getText();
        if (s.equals(a)) {

            found =true;

             system.out.println(size);
            break;
        }

    }
    if(!found){
    //find startx,starty, and Endy
    driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, duration);
 }

}
```

Comment: if(!found){
    //find startx,starty, and Endy
    driver.swipe(startx, starty, endx, endy, duration);
 }  Can you Explain this alone because the 'found' not seems to be declared

Comment: x,y are handled with dynamically? by taking the width and height of the device?